# confusion between pdo and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I read many threads in stackoverflow and also googled but i still have one confusion

Please Tell me which will be better for me if i will have following

Database : MYSQL

1. 10 000 Records in about 10 tables
2. 100 tables
3. 100 requests per second

i want to make website in which above details can be occur in future

if there are 100 users are viewing my site concurrently which will be best PDO or mysqli

Comment: I would think there will hardly be any difference. *Maybe* mysqli will be slightly faster. Why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: you should be more worried about your table storage engine rather than how you are accessing the DB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb

Comment: @PaulBain link you gave does not give my answer

Comment: @PaulBain my confusion is between pdo and mysqli

Comment: What are you **confused** about?!

Comment: as in it doesn't really matter in terms of performance. your bottleneck will likely not be the adapter, it'll be how you configure your database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Choosing an API](http://es.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) chapter in the PHP manual says this:

> The overall
>   performance of all three extensions is considered to be about the
>   same. Although the performance of the extension contributes only a
>   fraction of the total run time of a PHP web request. Often, the impact
>   is as low as 0.1%.

To sum up: if performance is your only concern, it's irrelevant which one you choose. (Not to mention that database size or complexity is basically MySQL Server's problem.)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion PDO is better than mysqli and there are no doubts. There are support for another databases, named parameters, easier SQL-Injection security (using prepared statements).

Mysqli is slightly faster, but i think it cannot be main reason in this case.